# How could I move, rotate the heading and stop a point using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am a Searcher in the Postgraduate level at faculty of Information Computing, and my graduation project involves a simulation for a  movement of multiple trains, i am trying to stop a point on a specified (x,y), then i want to rotate its heading and change the (angle) of its heading.
i have watched all of  this videos on your youtube channel about :
 "Basic C# Game Programming Moving Object on the form " here : [Illustrating Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eIzmcTe0mg)
which illustrates how to control the movement of the point using the KeyDown Event in the .NET, but i want to enter different locations at different times ( it will be stored in a variable and entered by a textbox or whatever ) , so if you please, guide and tell me how to rotate the heading of the point when arrived to a specified (x,y) and also how to stop it on its station (another (x,y)) in the railway network .
and if that is related to "grid networking" ??

---

i have found that system.Drawing has a function, which can be overloaded such as : 
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(30.0F); , but i found that it is not only rotate the transform, but also changes its location, you can check it by yourself.

---

also i tried this method :

---

```
    int x_ex = 60, y_ex = 60;
    private void increase_distance(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // draw a rectangl  
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, x_ex, y_ex, 20, 20);
        // increase or decrease it's movement
        x_ex = x_ex + (int)2.5;
        y_ex = y_ex + (int)2.5;
        // try to stop and rotate it 
        if (x_ex == 90)
        {

             //x_ex = (int)e.Graphics.Transform.RotateAt(30.0F, search on google
            // (RotateTransform method) not only rotate the object but also change the location and its coordinates 
            e.Graphics.RotateTransform(30.0F);
            // you can notice that its color will be changed for a fraction of moment when (x_ex=90)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, 90, 90, 20, 20);



            //x_ex = 0;
            //y_ex = 0;
```

help me if you please, your help & response already will be appreciated.

Comment: This may not apply in your scenario, but have you looked into doing the simulation using Unity (you can code in C# as well)? It will handle position vectors and rotation quaternions for you in a much simpler and object oriented manner. You could also stop at a station using Collision Triggers, and things like that.

Comment: Rotation rotates the canvas. It does not rotate the shape that you are drawing right now.

Comment: Usually you need to use RotateTransform in conjunction with TranslateTransform : Use the latter to move the rotation point to the origin, then the former to rotate the canvas. Then Draw! When done ResetTransform!